# Kendo NumericTextBox doesn't accept Unicode numbers (number from other languages)

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm using Kendo NumericTextBox in my project.
When the keyboard is not set in English, the NumericTextBox doesn't accept numbers.

for example when the keyboard is set to Persian and you type "۳۸" which is equivalent to "38", the NumericTextBox will become empty and reject the typed number.

how can i make NumericTextBox to accept "۳۸" or replace that with 38?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the culture using

```
$("#numerictextbox").kendoNumericTextBox({
    culture: "de-DE"
});
```

More about the available cultures here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/globalization/intl/overview

Sample from telerik how to implement it:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox/configuration/culture